# Rails .each show once for duplicate results

Tags: ruby-on-rails, each, uniq

Within a rails `.each` code, how can I eliminate duplicates from the result?

PMRelationships is a relationship table that links people and movies 
MGRelationships is a relationship table that links genres and movies

The process Im looking for is to find All a Person's genres through first PmRelationship then MgRelationship

```
<% @pm_relationships = PmRelationship.where(:people_id => @person.id) %>

<ul class="basic-info-genres">
  <% @pm_relationships.each do |pm_relationship| %>
    <% @movie=Movie.find(pm_relationship.movie_id) %>
    <% @mg_relationships = MgRelationship.where(:movie_id => @movie.id) %>
    <% @mg_relationships.each do |mg_relationship| %>
      <% @genre=Genre.find(mg_relationship.genre_id) %>
      <%= @genre.name %>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
</ul>
```

For example, this code returns a list of values, as such:

Action
Action
Comedy
Thriller
Adventure
Noir
Action

How can I make it so that It removes the two Lorems and only show one

Basically, Get rid of any duplication to return a list as such

Action
Comedy
Thriller
Adventure
Noir

***UPDATE***

I've changed my simplified code to match that of my actual app

I am aware most of this needs to be in the controller but simplified sake I'm doing it in the views first

Side note to those who could mention that I needn't create _Relationship tables and could simply use models has_many_belongs_to etc.., I find the Relationship table method much easier to handle and control

Thanks and apologies for the confusion

Comment: you are looking for unique latin names or unique values of worlds?

Comment: In your another question, I forgot to uniq `genre_ids`. I offer a new answer here, use `|=` to push members into the array and uniq it at the same time.

Comment: I guess your original code may be too complex to prevent you from refactoring. I strongly recommend you to spend time to refactoring your code with the code that the other answers suggested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are aware that your can use `associations`, I highly recommend it. It will help you to clean up the code and will save database queries.

Another thing, you are missing `<li></li>` inside `<ul></ul>`.

Anyways, as per your current code, you can just populate your all `@genre.name` in a `Set`

```
# as you said in question, following code should be moved to controller
genre_names = Set.new
<% @pm_relationships = PmRelationship.where(:people_id => @person.id) %>

<% @pm_relationships.each do |pm_relationship| %>
  <% @movie=Movie.find(pm_relationship.movie_id) %>
  <% @mg_relationships = MgRelationship.where(:movie_id => @movie.id) %>

  <% @mg_relationships.each do |mg_relationship| %>
    <% @genre=Genre.find(mg_relationship.genre_id) %>
    <% genre_names.add(@genre.name) %>    
  <% end %>
<% end%>

# actual view code
<ul class="basic-info-genres">
  <%= "<li>#{genre_names.to_a.join('</li><li>')}</li>".html_safe %>
</ul>
```

May be you want to read more about [**Set**](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.2/libdoc/set/rdoc/Set.html)

NOTE: After moving code to corresponding files, use appropriate variable types in controller and view, as required

Comment: Hi thanks for your detailed answer, i've implemented this and I'm getting `undefined method join for #<Set:0x007faafcd505f8>` this line here `<li>#{genre_names.join('</li><li>')}</li>`

Comment: Try `<%= "<li>#{genre_names.to_a.join('</li><li>')}</li>".html_safe %>`

Comment: `to_i` didnt work but I tried `to_a` and it worked perfectly, many many many many thanks to you sir. A problem i thought i would never fix

Comment: I'm just going to check a few more things before i give the bounty, give me a sec

Comment: Sure @PMP, `to_i` was typo... :P my bad.. you exactly got what I wanted to write

Comment: Hey sorry to bother again, but i was wondering if you could show me how a link_to would work in the print code you provided <%= "<a><li><button><span>#{genre_names.to_a.join('</span></button></li></a><a><li><‌​button><span>')}</span></button></li></a>".html_safe %> have this link to  /genres/<%=@genre.id%>? I've tried <%= "<a href='/genres/#{@genre.id}'><li><button><span>#{genre_names.to_a.join('</span></‌​button></li></a><a><li><button><span>')}</span></button></li></a>".html_safe %> but this only links to the first genre shown @RAJ...

Comment: I guess new ques with reference of this ques and ans will be great to discuss over.. Here it's getting messy and no one else will be able to get benefit from it. @PMP

Comment: Sure thing http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25157456/rails-link-to-an-each-join @RAJ...

Answer (score 1):

Try to replace your original code:

```
<% @mg_relationships.each do |mg_relationship| %>
<% @genre=Genre.find(mg_relationship.genre_id) %>
  <%= @genre.name %>
<% end %>
```

To:(this version did not broken your code structure, just change the position of the output code)

```
<% genre_names = []%>
<% @mg_relationships.each do |mg_relationship| %>
<% @genre=Genre.find(mg_relationship.genre_id) %>
  <%#= @genre.name %>
  <% genre_names |= [@genre.name]%>
<% end %>

<%= genre_names %> or <%= genre_names.join(" ") %>
```

Comment: <%= genre_names %> returns `["Comedy", "Fantasy", "Holiday", "Family"]
["Comedy"]
["Action", "Adventure", "Fantasy", "Science Fiction"]
["Comedy"]`      and `<%= genre_names.join(" ") %>` returns `Comedy Fantasy Holiday Family Comedy Action Adventure Fantasy Science` Fiction Comedy

Comment: Then you just use `<%= genre_names.uniq %>` or `<%= genre_names.uniq.join(" ") %>` can get uniq result. But `<% genre_names |= [@genre.name]%>` cannot create duplicate members, `[1,2] | [2,3]` => `[1,2,3]`. May be you have another problem. I have to go, wish you can solve the problem by your own. I think all the answers you've got is enough for you. You just need time to understand.

Comment: Do you not know of a way to group all the values returned from a .each call and then be able to call that group outside of the .each method?

Answer (score 0):

Using the `uniq` method on `Array`, you'll be able to remove duplicates.

See here for reference: http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Array.html#method-i-uniq

Answer (score 0):

```
<% @worlds.collect(&:latin).uniq.each do |latin| %>
  <%= latin.name %>
<% end %>
```

This assumes there's a belongs_to association between World and Latin (I assumed this because of the World#latin_id field and the fact there's a model called Latin).

EDIT:  if you have multiple Latin objects with the same name then collect the names then do `uniq`:

```
<% @worlds.collect(&:latin).collect(&:name).uniq.each do |name| %>
  <%= name %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: This still renders the duplications

Comment: Ah, so you have multiple latin objects with the same name.  See my edit.

Comment: btw `collect` is the same as `map`.  I always use collect because i used to do Java and a map in java is like a ruby Hash, which i found confusing when i switched.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this to get uniq latin name

```
 <% @worlds.collect(&:latin).collect(&:name).uniq.each do |latin_name| %>
   <%= latin_name %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: This still renders the duplications

Comment: did you get duplicate name as `collect(&:name).uniq` will remove duplication of name