# Rails turn set of .each values into Array-type

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays

I am using a .each method to find a list of genres

```
<% @mg_relationships.each do |mg_relationship| %>
    <% @genre = Genre.find(mg_relationship.genre_id) %>
       <%= @genre.id %>
<% end %>
```

This code returns the following

```
35 14 10595 10751 35 28 12 14 878 35
```

What i need to be able to do is to, outside of the each call, have the above output transformed into an array-like format, called `@array` for example, as such:

```
[35, 14, 10595, 10751, 35, 28, 12, 14, 878, 35]
```

So that i can then use <%= @array.uniq! %> to filter how to similar values and return

```
[35, 14, 10595, 10751, 28, 12, 878]
```

Comment: Is there a relation mg_relationship belongs_to :genre ?

Comment: If you already have the genre_id then why are you looking up the genre to find get the genre id?

Comment: I updated my answer, wish it helps.

Comment: can you post the output of `@mg_relationships.inspect`

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to query the `Genre` model, you already have `genre_id`. Just use [`pluck`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Calculations/pluck), on the model or association:

```
MgRelationship.pluck(:genre_id)
```

If you need the results to be unique, you can apply `.uniq` to the scope to generate a `select distinct`:

```
MgRelationship.uniq.pluck(:genre_id)
```

Comment: ... It's all the code you need to produce `[35, 14, 10595, 10751, 28, 12, 878]`.

Comment: This instead returns other values which weren't requested in the first place

Comment: Then you need to give us more information on where `@mg_relationship` is coming from.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<%= Genre.where(id: @mg_relationships.pluck(&:genre_id)).map(&:id) %>
```

Comment: This returns `35 14 10595 10751 [35, 14, 10595, 10751] 35 [35] 28 12 14 878 [28, 12, 14, 878] 35 [35]`

Comment: Im just still trying to find a solution from my unanswered question, more details here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25018971/rails-each-show-once-for-duplicate-results

Comment: What is the content on @mg_relationships ?

Comment: movie_id and genre_id, connect a movie to a genre and vice versa

Answer (score 0):

Meagar's answer is quite well, but I want to offer another way.

```
Genre.where('exists (select 1 from Mg_Relationships 
             where Mg_Relationships.genre_id = genres.id)').pluck(:id)
```

It have the same effect of `MgRelationship.uniq.pluck(:genre_id)`, but when the MgRelationships data includes some genres.id do not exists in genres, you can get rid of them at the same time.

**EDIT:**

I reviewed your question, realized that we may all missunderstand you.

You said you want `outside of the each call, to get @arrary`. I guess you just want fetch DBMS once, to populate two kinds of content to the view.

If I guess so, try this:

```
<% genre_ids = []%>
<% @mg_relationships.each do |mg_relationship| %>
    <% @genre = Genre.find(mg_relationship.genre_id) %>
       <%#= @genre.id %>
       <% genre_ids << @genre.id  %>
<% end %>

<% = genre_ids %>
<% = genre_ids.uniq %>
```

In veiws, You can write any ruby code without output to browser just with `<% %>` instead of `<% = ...%>`

But we have to say your original code have big problem about efficiency, that's why all the answers are suggest you to change to map or pluck.

If you have 10 mg_relationships, your original code will generate 11 sql statements to execute. All the answers to suggest you is to generate only one sql statement to do the same thing.

Wish you can understand our suggestion, and improve your code.

Comment: This simply returns a set of different values

Comment: Many thanks for your answer and your time, the code you provided seems to just 'mirror' the code above it, as such                  35 14 10595 10751
[35, 14, 10595, 10751]
35
[35]
28 12 14 878
[28, 12, 14, 878]
35
[35]  I think this is perhaps due to the each function contains the Mg.each function, i thought perhaps asking a new question with solely that code could fix it but it doesn't seem so. If you take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25018971/rails-each-show-once-for-duplicate-results, it's an extended version of this question but where the answer would come down to the same

Comment: I tried to simplify it in a new question as the aforementioned one wasn't receiving any answers, if you any ideas there's a bounty set on it and it would be much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

A few of the answers above will do, but for what you want since you already have the `@mg_relationships` variable how about just simply:

`@mg_relationships.map{|mg| mg.genre_id}.uniq!`

Comment: This doesn't show anything. If i get rid of uniq! and put the code outside the each, it shows only [35]. If i put it in the each, without uniq!, it shows 35
[35, 14, 10595, 10751]
14
[35, 14, 10595, 10751]
10595
[35, 14, 10595, 10751]
10751
[35, 14, 10595, 10751]
35
[35]
28
[28, 12, 14, 878]
12
[28, 12, 14, 878]
14
[28, 12, 14, 878]
878
[28, 12, 14, 878]
35
[35]

Comment: hmmm it shouldn't need to be inside the .each at all, should just do the operation on the variable itself outside