# Rails link_to an .each join

Tags: ruby-on-rails, join, hyperlink, set

I have this code which associates one table to another. Using Set it collects all data and only shows it once if there are other similar values.

```
genre_names = Set.new
<% @pm_relationships = PmRelationship.where(:people_id => @person.id) %>

<% @pm_relationships.each do |pm_relationship| %>
  <% @movie=Movie.find(pm_relationship.movie_id) %>
  <% @mg_relationships = MgRelationship.where(:movie_id => @movie.id) %>

  <% @mg_relationships.each do |mg_relationship| %>
    <% @genre=Genre.find(mg_relationship.genre_id) %>
    <% genre_names.add(@genre.name) %>    
  <% end %>
<% end%>

# actual view code
<ul class="basic-info-genres">
  <%= "<li>#{genre_names.to_a.join('</li><li>')}</li>".html_safe %>
</ul>
```

My problem here is how a link_to would work in the print code provided

`<%= "<a><li><button><span>#{genre_names.to_a.join('</span></button></li></a><a><li><‌​‌​button><span>')}</span></button></li></a>".html_safe %>`

How to make the above print to have this link to `/genres/<%=@genre.id%>`?

I've tried

`<%= "<a href='/genres/#{@genre.id}'><li><button><span>#{genre_names.to_a.join('</span></‌​‌​button></li></a><a><li><button><span>')}</span></button></li></a>".html_safe %>`

but this only links to the first genre shown

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add to genres the whole @genres, not only the @genre-name, then you can use the each-loop in the view code.

For the Controller (you should have your programmic logic there):

```
 @genres = Set.new 
 @pm_relationships = PmRelationship.where(:people_id => @person.id) 
 @pm_relationships.each do |pm_relationship| 
   movie=Movie.find(pm_relationship.movie_id) 
   @mg_relationships = MgRelationship.where(:movie_id => movie.id)
   @mg_relationships.each do |mg_relationship| %>
     genre=Genre.find(mg_relationship.genre_id) %>
     @genres.add(genre) %>    
   end
 end
```

For the view:

```
 <ul class="basic-info-genres">
   <% @genres.each do |genre| %>
     <li><%= link_to genre.genre_name, "#{root_url}genres/#{genre.id}" %></li>
   <% end %>
 </ul>
```

Comment: Using `genres.each` returns `undefined local variable or method genre`,if i use `genre_names.each`i get the same output except that the link is the same for all genres

Comment: Of course you have to define @genres then. I've updated the post with the corresponding code for the controller.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to link all genres that are associated with a movie.

To do this, in your controller, load the genres for a user's movies.  With the correct association setup, this is as easy as `@person.genres`.  So let's do that.

```
  class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :pm_relationships
    has_many :movies, through: :pm_relationships
    has_many :genres, through: :movies
  end

  class PmRelationship < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :person
    belongs_to :movie
  end

  class Movie < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :mg_relationships
    has_many :genres, through: :mg_relationships
  end
```

With that setup, in your controller, just setup an instance variable to list all genres for `@person`

```
@genres = @person.genres
```

Then in your view, use the block form of `link_to` so it's easier to code your html

```
<ul class="basic-info-genres">
  <% @genres.each do |genre| %>
    <%= link_to genre do %>
      <li>
        <button>
          <span><%= genre.name %>‌</span>
        </button>
      </li>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you can't have any direct child element instead of `li` within `ul`. You will need to have `<a>` within `li`, however, we can apply css to `<a>` so that it looks like whole 'li' have the clickable link.

From your actual code, update the snippet.

```
<ul class="basic-info-genres">
  <% genre_names.each do |genre_name| %>
    <li>
      <%= link_to genre_name, genre_path(@genre), :class => 'clickable-li' %>
    </li>
  <% end %>
</ul>
```

You need to set your `<a>` to `display: block;`

```
# css file
.clickable-li {
  display: block;
}
```